# What is the variable name of my JTable's model in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, tablesorter

Using the example [`TableFilterDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java), I'm trying to create a `RowFilter` in NetBeans, but I can't. I tried the [code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableFilterDemoProject/src/components/TableFilterDemo.java) in `JCreator`; I need help.

I understand that I do not need to create `class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel`  because I already manually did this in NetBeans GUI tools. Now, I face a problem in defining the model with `RowSorter`.

```
MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModel>(model);
table = new JTable(model);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

Above is the example, and I change it to this:

```
private TableRowSorter<javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel> sorter;
/** Creates new form NewJFrame */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel>(model);
    JTable jTable = new JTable(model);
    jTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Is it correct? I can't get this to work. I suspect is the sorter is not added into the table. Which maybe because of defining model part. Please give advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not nessesary to you create your abstract table model .
you just use defaultModel and use following code

`voterTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(65);`

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you create the JTable in the GUI Builder. You have too add the model to this table and not to a new one you create.

Replace the method with :

```
public NewJFrame() {
   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
   sorter = new TableRowSorter<javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel>(model);
   initComponents();
}
```

And add the rowsorter from the GUI Builder (will be added in `initComponent()`):

- Right click on the JTable -> Properties -> Pane "Code"
- In Custom Creation code  write -> `new JTable(model);`
- In Variable name you will see the variable name ([table_name] in following point)
- In Post Creation Code write -> `[table_name].setRowSorter(sorter);`